# Canvas element inside a foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Okay so my javascript and canvas work outside the loop, but when its in the loop there are issues.

1. I have to manually run the javascript inside the console (just copied pasted the original  code then hit run), this will fire then return `Object[canvas#myCanvas]`, parts of the javascript work before manually entering it into the console, but some functionality won't. Manually running it all works fine.
2. Even after manually running it, the canvas elements inside the other looped items don't work, so it only works on the first element.

**Javascript:** *I set this in the footer (when inside the header it doesnt load properly, under the canvas would result in the code looping, so footer worked best). I used `window.onload`, and `$(document).ready()`, but it works without and since it's in the footer it's loaded after the canvas.*

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasOffset = $("#myCanvas").offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
}
img.src = "http://localhost/stat-tracker/images/basketball-court.png";

function is2Point(x, y) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 31);
    console.log(ctx.bezierCurveTo(260, 50, 200, 250, 0, 257));
    ctx.closePath();
    if (ctx.isPointInPath(x, y)) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "gold";
        ctx.fill();
        return (true);
    }
    return (false);
}

function isInside(x, y) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(76, 190, 125, 90);
    if (ctx.isPointInPath(x, y)) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        ctx.fill();
        return (true);
    }
    return (false);
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
    x = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    y = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    if (!isInside(x, y) && !is2Point(x, y)) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
        ctx.stroke();
    }

}

$("#myCanvas").mousemove(function (e) {
    console.log(handleMouseMove(e));
});
```

**PHP:** *It is nested inside more divs but here is an idea how its looped.*

```
<?php foreach($playerData as $key => $player): ?>
  <?php foreach($player as $teamkey => $team): ?>
    <div class="<?php echo $teamkey ?>">
    <?php foreach($team as $playernamekey => $playername): ?>
      <?php foreach($playername as $statskey => $stats): ?>
        <div class="add-stat-data"> 
        <!-- Shot chart here -->
        <img id="court-image" src="./images/basketball-court.png">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
        </div>
      <?php endforeach;  ?>
    <?php endforeach;  ?>
    </div>
  <?php endforeach;  ?>
<?php endforeach;  ?>
```

The result I am getting (refer to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/a4gUH/)) is that some functions are not showing on mouse move, specifically the green and yellow.

Again testing one more time, copying the canvas/image to the top near the body works, fine. So I want to say I am 98% sure it's the foreach. **@Pointy** pointed out and is right I shouldnt be looping an element with an ID? Is this where the problem lies, do I need to make it a class?

**UPDATE:** I updated my code with a timeout, I wrapped the above javascript with `var zoneCanvas = function() {}` then set  a 5 second timeout on the function. It worked, not an idea solution though, is it because my canvas is being loaded after the script?

```
setTimeout(function() {
    zoneCanvas();
},5000)
```

**UPDATE:** Okay I am not sure if this is ideal, but I set `var canvas = document.querySelector(".chart-is-opened .myCanvas")` to the active element that has the canvas, I also set a timeout `setTimeout(function() {
                zoneCanvas();
                },0)` the function is inside an click event, so when a new chart is opened it reloads the function then the canvas element is now the active one.

Hopefully that makes sense id be glad to post more code, but I am scared this make cause DOM bubbling or it isn't an ideal soltuion? Any advice on re-loading the function every time with a timeout?

Comment: Where's the `forEach` loop?  Are you generating multiple `<canvas>` elements with the same "id" value?  You should not do that; "id" values have to be **unique**.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I try to keep that in mind, didn't think too much of that here. Ill try using it as a class? but in the javascript we get the canvas like this `var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");` care to elaborate on tweaking that out instead of looping the id? *Looking back at the code, thankfully I am not looping any ID elements, only the canvas because all tutorials use an ID*

Comment: `document.querySelector('.someClass');`

Comment: Using a class didn't change anything, I am going to keep trying.

Comment: I took out the foreach and it's still an issue, maybe its css/positioning. Going to keep fiddling.

Comment: Okay so It's not CSS, when I fire the javacript in the console it works fine?

Answer (score 1):

I have a project with multiple canvases that get looped over and the issue I ran into was that the context needs to be set to the current canvas.  I ended up making the variable ctx global, and set it on any function that used the canvas, for example:

```
function startBrush(canvasID, color, lineWidth, x1, y1) { // called from mouse down
    ctx=$('#'+canvasID)[0].getContext('2d');
    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.beginPath();
}

function drawBrush(canvasID, color, lineWidth, x1, y1) { // called from mouse move
    ctx.strokeStyle=color;
    ctx.lineWidth=lineWidth;
    ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I see what you're doing, I came up with a solution that works well so far for me (posted above). When I get done writing a portion I am working on now Id like to try this, ill get back to you when I do :) Thanks for sharing.